# How to perform arithmetic on every row of a file via piping

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic-expressions

Lets say we have a simple file `data.txt` which has the following content:

```
1
2
3
```

Is there a command to perform arithmetic on every row value of the file via piping? I'm looking for something like `cat data.txt | arit "+10"` which would output:

```
11
12
13
```

The best thing I know is performing arithmetic by using `bc` for *individual* values, for example `echo "1+10" | bc`, but I wasn't able to apply this to my own example which contains many values with trailing newlines.

Answer (score 2):

You could use awk:

```
awk '{print $1+10}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

My first impulse is to use `sed`. (Hey, it's the tool I always reach for.)

```
cat data.txt | sed 's/$/+10/' | bc
```

**EDIT:** or like so

```
sed 's/$/+10/' data.txt | bc
```